# Adding exception to a while loop in stripping html from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I'm using this code snippet to strip HTML from a string that I am sending to a `UIWebView`:

```
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

It's getting rid of most everything I need to eradicate (many unnecessary divs, etc.), except I need to retain tags like `<strong>` and `<p>` for basic formatting purposes. Is there any way to retain these by creating an exception in the while loop?

Comment: You can play a little trick here. Change all <strong> to ~strong~ first. Then remove all tags and then switch back all ~strong~ to <strong>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do like this,

```
NSArray *tagsToKeep = @[@"<strong>",@"<p>"];
NSString *keyIn = @"|KEYIN|";
NSString *keyOut = @"|KEYOUT|";
/// Encrypt text
for (NSString *tagToKeep in tagsToKeep)
{
    NSString *encryptedTag = [tagToKeep stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:keyIn];
    encryptedTag = [encryptedTag stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:keyOut];
    s =[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:tagToKeep withString:encryptedTag];
}

/// Parse
while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
{
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
}

/// Decrypt text
for (NSString *tagToKeep in tagsToKeep)
{
    NSString *encryptedTag = [tagToKeep stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:keyIn];
    encryptedTag = [encryptedTag stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:keyOut];
    s =[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:encryptedTag withString:tagToKeep];
}
```

Update : same solution than "Sam B" in the previous comment.